# JavaScript: bracket notation to retrieve property values

Tags: javascript

I'm working on codecademy.com JavaScript tutorial. This lesson on objects.  I have a feeling this problem is fairly simple, but I'm not getting the answer. If I understood the instructions better, the answer might be clearer to me.

I set the value to the variable aProperty, and now I'm supposed to follow the instructions in the final comment, i.e. print the value of the first property using the variable "aProperty". I've included the "intro to the lesson" below to help explain what the lesson is trying to teach.

The Question: Assuming I set the variable aProperty correctly, how would you retrieve the first value of the James object using the variable aProperty.

```
var james = {
    job: "programmer",
    married: false
};

// set to the first property name of "james"
var aProperty = james.job; 

// print the value of the first property of "james" 
// using the variable "aProperty"
```

**Intro to lesson**

> And finally, let's go over retrieving property values. Throughout this section, we've been using dot notation to get the value of an object's property:
>
> ```
> someObj.propName
> ```
>
> However, remember that we can also use bracket notation:
>
> ```
> someObj["propName"]
> ```
>
> An advantage of bracket notation is that we are not restricted to just using strings in the brackets. We can also use variables whose values are property names:
>
> ```
> var someObj = {propName: someValue}; var myProperty = "propName"; someObj[myProperty]
> ```
>
> The last line is exactly the same as using someObj["propName"].
>
> Take advantage of the ability to use variables with bracket notation.
>
> In line 7, set aProperty to a string of the first property in james (ie. the job property).
>
> Then print james's job using bracket notation and aProperty.

Comment: Do they want you to iterate through all properties of the object James until you find a value that matches aProperty?

Comment: @NicholasAlbion—that's what I first thought, but I think they're after Alnitak's answer.

Comment: There is this nice example in the description: `var myProperty = "propName"; someObj[myProperty]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var aProperty = 'job';
console.log(james[aProperty]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var james = {
job: "programmer",
married: false
};

var aProperty = "job";

console.log( james[aProperty] );
```

Comment: That's what was answered and accepted back in 2012, too; why bother adding to solved problems without adding anything new?